# Is there an alternative to an OpenGL IndexBuffer

Tags: opengl

Is there an alternative to an OpenGL indexbuffer? 
I have a `std::vector<glm::vec3>` with a lot of vertex Positions which, when I draw them as points, they become a sphere grid. All points are sorted in planes and each plane has a different number of points. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnw6p.jpg) is a picture of the grid.

I would like to connect them to get a solid sphere. I know, I can do this with an index buffer but since I have 710 points I would like to know if there is an easier way of doing this. I looked into tessellation but I think that is not the right way to go. I only would like to have a clue or an idea. I'm pretty new to OpenGL.

Comment: OpenGL has no special commands to join the points (apart from lines or triangles). You have to implement the logic needed to join them forming triangles.

Comment: hm ..so I have to create an Indexbuffer containing all the triangles.

Comment: You do need a buffer with coordinates. If you want another one with indices... that's a choice, sometimes good, sometimes not that good.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

> `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle`

(rather than glDrawElements) you should be able to draw without an index buffer. However, your vertices need to be sorted so that this works, i.e. three successive vertices always have to build one triangle of the sphere. Thus, you need to multiply send vertices to the graphics card, once for every triangle they are in. This is usually covered in the first tutorials, like on [opengl-tutorials.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/)
(That's also where i got the code from).
However, that also leads you to the problem of "specifying" the triangles, which you can't get around, because OpenGL doesn't "just know" how to connect the vertices, as Ripi2 already mentioned